# Cronbach's alpha for a questionnaire consisting of several scales

Tags: r, cronbachs-alpha

Suppose I have data from a questionnaire. The questionnaire contained eight items, of which the first four comprise one scale, the second four another scale. My data now looks like this:

```
dat:
            | scale.1                     | scale.2
participant | item.1 item.2 item.3 item.4 | item.5 item.6 item.7 item.8
1           | 3      7      1      2      | 2      3      6      4
2           | 2      2      5      2      | 8      9      7      6
...
```

How do I calculate Cronbach’s alpha for this questionnaire as a whole and each individual scale?

When I calculate alpha for scale.1, do I calculate it *as if the items comprising scale.2 did not exist* ? Like this:

```
library(psy)
cronbach(data.frame(dat$item.1, dat$item.2, dat$item.3, dat$item.4))
```

Or is there some (better? correct?) way where I input the whole dataframe into a function, tell it which columns belong to which scale, and I get internal consistencies that considers the scales in the context of the whole questionnaire? `scoreItems` from the psych package seems to do something like this, but I'm too stupid to make sense of the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cronbach's alpha is a measure of internal consistency of a scale. It makes sense to do it for scale 1 separately and for scale 2 separately but there seems no point in doing it for the whole questionnaire when there are supposed to be separate sub-scales.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to calculating two reliability or alpha coefficients (as @mdewey rightly suggested), you may also have a look at $\omega_h$ (hierarchical omega) and $\omega_h$ (omega total), which are very useful for "multidimensional" item sets. The first one is a measure of variability due to a general "g-factor", and the second one is a measure of variability due to both a general and group factors (scale.1 and scale.2 would be the group factors in your example). Definitely look at Revelle's sources for his `psych` package (e.g., http://personality-project.org/r/psych/HowTo/R_for_omega.pdf and [Chapter 7.2.5 of his book on psychometric theory](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/Chapter7.pdf).